# slowness for chat messages in Skypebot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, skype, skype-bots

I have created a Skypebot application in Node JS. Recently we face slowness for chat messages in Skypebot . Some times we don't see messages in skype , once we close open the skype  messages are displayed at once.

Skype bot app uses some commands to communicate to other users, but due to the slowness of message it doesn't executes the commands properly.

These issues happened recently only and we are facing this for last 4-5 months.

Any suggestion/help, how I could resolve this?

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/304

Answer (score 0):

Skype bots are deprecated. I recommend switching to another platform, like Teams.

Comment: This bot app is working for last 2 year without any issue in Skype. So I cannot switch in to another channel.

Comment: Why can't you switch to another channel?

Comment: @ Kyle Delaney - we are keeping the conversation details in SQLite3 database and it won't be possible to switch the channel at this stage. Because all the Bot process flow are maintained using the conversation ID and it may be different for the channel.

Comment: Is this due to the issue of Skype channel?

Comment: Switching to a new platform would mean having your users use that new platform, which would mean starting new conversations. It's unclear what's causing the problems you're seeing, but the point is that you won't be able to get help with those problems since you're using Skype. Is this answer acceptable?

Comment: We are doing some logic flow using the Conversation Id of the user. Since the Conversation Id of the user will be different  for each channel we cannot switch this to another channel. We are managing some registration process based on this Conversation Id.  For skype channel the conversation Id is like "29:1mKNIVkZ...1" and for teams it is some what like "19:22abc...." . In case we move to another channel, we have to modify the entire existing logics .

Comment: Are you saying the problem is that conversation ID's will be different, or are you saying the problem is that the conversation ID's will be formatted differently? If you're saying there's some kind of compatibility issue based on the formatting, can you explain what you're doing with a Skype conversation ID that wouldn't work with a Teams conversation ID?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Any other options rather than moving the channel?

Comment: Your other option is to continue using Skype with the knowledge that it won't work well and that there's no Skype team that will help you